# POST is not getting current values from angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

In my view there are two forms (one is visible, second one is hidden). First one as action calls `submit1()` function in controller, that in turn will invoke `document.getElementById('form2').submit();` Second form action has method `POST` that directly calls php.

Now I cannot get why if my `submit1()` looks like this:

```js
function submit1()
{
 // doesnt matter
 $scope.first = 'this is my string';   // here I'm modifying variable from $scope1 that is directly in form2
 document.getElementById('form2').submit(); // problem here!

 // doesn't matter
}
```

It does not work as expected.

Basically, when `form2` is sent, it still has a default value (not changed one).
Looks like it would not really change variable outside the scope of function `submit1()` or like `POST` would not accept this change. Anyone can tell me why it is like that?

Moreover I was previously using $http post method instead `document.getElement().submit()` and it works fine. So this seems to be weird.

I would appreciate any help in this matter.
Thank you!

Edit1: (adding more code to properly define what is a problem):

```js
view:
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <div ng-hide="true" >
  <form action="./order2.php" id="form2" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username" value="{{username}}"/>
   <input type="text" name="phone" value="{{phone}}"/>
   <input type="text" name="address" value="{{address}}"/>
   <input type="text" name="price" value="{{totalPrice}}"/>
   <input type="text" name="email" value="{{email}}"/>
   <input type="text" name="message" value="{{text}}"/>
   
   <input type="submit"/>
  </form>

 </div>
 
 <form novalidate id="contact-form" name="contactForm">

  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit1()" href>
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg"></i> 
   {{ 'ID_ORDER_BUTTON' | translate:$root.currentLang }}
  </a>    
 </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```js
Appcontrollers.controller('controller1', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, $routeParams, $window, $location, databaseService, translationService, cartService, leatherService, $location) {
 $scope.text="";
 $scope.email="11111@2222.com";
 $scope.price=0;
 $scope.address= "add";
 $scope.phone="1213131";
 $scope.username="usera";
 
  
 $scope.submit1 = function() {
  $scope.price=999999999; // this looks like doesn't have effect.
  document.getElementById('form2').submit(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say something with this *pseudo* code.

Comment: Show all relevant code. Can't see any reason to ever need to submit this way either

Comment: Added more code. Thank you guys. I'm just wondering why when I switch to $http it works ok, but 'classic' POST does not work - is it anyhow defined/expected behavior?

Comment: 2 questions: Why aren't you using `ngModel`? Why do you need 2 forms?

Comment: developer033, re. ngModel will it change anything in this case? Re. 2 forms. Well most likely it could be bound into one, however still I dont see why this is not working :( OR in case you see difference can you modify above code to make it working?